# Putting a variable into name of function javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to do the following:

```
var table = new google.visualization.XXXXX(document.getElementById(divId));
```

where the X's represent a variable that is set previously.

Just so you know, I'm using Google visualizations here, but I don't think that is necessarily relevant to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use square bracket notation.

```
var XXXXX = "someString";
var table = new google.visualization[XXXXX](document.getElementById(divId));
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple:

```
var table = new google.visualization[XXXXX](document.getElementById(divId));
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: That's wonderful, I really should have caught on to this earlier. Thanks, Robin and David.