# JavaScript, How can I parse a variable into a command?

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables, command

What I'm trying to do is to enable multiple checkboxes within `for()`.  Right now it looks like this, but from what I have learned, you can't run the command from a variable like this, I can't run, (e.g) `cab_type_value = "whatever"`. Nor can I run `road_load_enabled`; it just doesn't work. Does anyone how I can achieve this? How can I parse my var `J` in the `document.MyForm.InputName.disabled`?

```
for( var j=1; j<=14; j++ ) {
    var cab_type_value = "document.exe_mode_form.cab_type" + j + ".value";
    var cab_type_checked = "document.exe_mode_form.cab_type" + j + ".checked == 1";

    for( var i=1; i<=document.exe_mode_form.road_load_number.value; i++ ) {
        var road_load_value = "document.exe_mode_form.load" + i + ".value";
        var road_load_enabled = "document.exe_mode_form.load" + i + ".disabled = false";
        var road_load_disabled = "document.exe_mode_form.load" + i + ".disabled = true";
        var rld_db = "document.exe_mode_form.a" + i + "_a1.value";

        if ( cab_type_checked ) {
            if ( test == 1 ) {
                if(road_load_disabled) {
                    alert("road_load_disabled");
                    road_load_enabled;
                }
                test = 2;
            }

            if(cab_type_value == rld_db) {
                if(olof == 1) {
                    alert("cab_type_value  == rld_db");
                    olof = 2;
                }

                road_load_enabled;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, this part isn't working:

```
if(cab_type_value == rld_db) {
    if(olof == 1){
        alert("cab_type_value  == rld_db");
        olof = 2;
    }

    road_load_enabled;
}
```

And I have checked, `cab_type_value` has the same value as `rld_db`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting a variable into name of function javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925949/putting-a-variable-into-name-of-function-javascript)

Comment: Well there's the right way and the wrong way. This is the wrong way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: why all commands are in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing these kind of lines:

```
var cab_type_value = "document.exe_mode_form.cab_type" + j + ".value";
```

to:

```
var cab_type_value = document.exe_mode_form['cab_type' + j].value;
```

The same logic holds for function calls:

```
someVariable = 'alert';
window[someVariable]('Foo!');//alerts foo
```

If your function is not declared in the global scope, you can replace `window` with any namespace object: `foobarObject.orEven.nestedOnes[someVariable]();`
And finally, because I personally loathe the `window` keyword (it's a circular reference), you can simply choose to use `this['alert']('foo');` in a regular function call or in the global scope. `this` points to its called context, which in these cases is the global object